# Vlookup In vba Code between two sheets is returning no values?

Tags: excel, vba

i have two worksheets, one is called sheet1, and the second is sheet2. what i want to do is take values from sheet1 and vlookup the values in sheet2, if the value exists in sheet2, return the 14 columns of sheet2 value.

i have a for loop that goes through all the values in sheet1, columns E and a vlookup function. but for some reason the vlookup is not returning a value even though the values are present in sheet2. here is my code.

```
Set myRang = shGL.Range("A13").CurrentRegion    
For k = 1 To EndRowReport
        If shReport.Range("D" & k).Value = "Bank Transaction Account" Then
            On Error Resume Next
            shReport.Range("F" & r).Offset(1, 0).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(shReport.Range("E" & r + 1).Value, myRang, 14, False)
            totalAmount = totalAmount + shReport.Range("C" & r).Offset(1, 0).Value
            totalAmountAbs = totalAmountAbs + shReport.Range("D" & r).Offset(1, 0).Value
            r = r + 1
        End If
   Next k
```

any kind of help or suggestion is highly appreciated!

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next`. This line hides **all** error messages but the errors still occur. You just cannot see their messages. If you don't see them you cannot fix them, if you don't fix them the code dose not work.

Comment: i tried it without it, however there was no change. the same result

Comment: `Debug.Print myRang.Address` - is it what you expect?

Comment: What is `r` set to in the beginning?

Comment: @abrahamfoto If it doesn't change anything, then remove that line. Doesn't make sense to have lines that can cause troubles but don't have an effect on your code now. You might benefit reading [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)

Comment: Is the table you're doing the VLookUp in organized as table?  That means each row is a unique record unto itself, so you don't have any information spread across two rows for the same record?  I was wondering becuase I noticed that the summing you're doing is using the value from the next row, not the current one.  VLookUps are intended to be used on tables with a unique lookup column, having a single row of data for unique value.  If your data isn't organized like this, then I would suggest using a Find call get the records you want.